# Managing vimeo videos within flutter

Tags: flutter, vimeo

I'm about to create an app to provide interactive videos which worked very well with youtube-video-controller.
But i need a vimeo video controller to manage the video state and perform a callback.
if anyone could help me with this i would be super gratefull.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this package: [flutter_youtube_vimeo](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_youtube_vimeo)

Install with

```
dependencies:
  flutter_youtube_vimeo: ^0.0.1
```